# Is there a way to ensure a function runs to the end before another starts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is what I do : I have a png plan for different sections in a library. In PyQt5 I have a button for each section which when pressed alternates the base png with a copy that has the corresponding section highlighted.

See my code below for my caveman solution to the problem.

It works but if I click the cdLoc button but don't wait for it to end and press the dvdLoc, dvdLoc will run through then will finish running cdLoc, highlighting the wrong section.

So my question - aside from any recommendations to better do this job - is whether there is a way to make functions run one at a time or forbid any other functions from launching while I'm running a specific function?

EDIT : I coudn't add the png files so instead I have it print the button output to the console. If you click Cds then Dvds before the first one is other, it will prints Cds at the end.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtTest
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 662)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 640, 562))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        pixmap = QPixmap('blank.png') 
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 580, 334, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.cds = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cds.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 130, 141, 23))
        self.cds.setObjectName("cds")
        self.dvd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.dvd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 160, 141, 23))
        self.dvd.setObjectName("dvd")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.cds.clicked.connect(self.cdLoc)
        self.dvd.clicked.connect(self.dvdLoc)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Library Plan"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Library plan"))
        self.cds.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cds"))
        self.dvd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dvds"))

    def cdLoc(self):
        print('cd') # I had to replace my code but so it can be tested but the orignal code uses these two lines instead of printing : pixmap = Pixmap('pictureName.png') and self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        print('base')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        print('cd')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        print('base')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        print('cd')

    def dvdLoc(self):
        print('dvd')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        print('base')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        print('dvd')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        print('base')
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        print('dvd')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, could provide a [mcve] to understand it better

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry. I edited the code so it could be reproduced. I coudn't add the png files so instead I have it print the button output to the console. If you click Cds then Dvds before the first one is other, it will prints Cds at the end. I hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, it is better understood, I have a question: Let's say that you press "cd" and you are printing "cd" on the console, but at that moment you press "dvd", I understand that you should not print "dvd", but that it happens after it finishes printing "cd", should it print "dvd" or not?

Comment: it should print dvd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> enabled : bool
>
> This property holds whether the widget is enabled
>
> In general an enabled widget handles keyboard and mouse events; a disabled widget does not.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5           import QtTest


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel()
        
        self.cdLocButton = QPushButton('cdLocButton')
        self.cdLocButton.clicked.connect(self.cdLoc)
        
        self.dvdLocButton = QPushButton('dvdLocButton')
        self.dvdLocButton.clicked.connect(self.dvdLoc)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.cdLocButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.dvdLocButton)        

    def cdLoc(self):
        self.dvdLocButton.setEnabled(False)                   # <---
        
        pixmap = QPixmap('Ok.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        pixmap = QPixmap('im.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        pixmap = QPixmap('Ok.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        pixmap = QPixmap('im.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        pixmap = QPixmap('Ok.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        
        self.dvdLocButton.setEnabled(True)                    # <---

    def dvdLoc(self):
        self.cdLocButton.setEnabled(False)
        pixmap = QPixmap('exit.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        pixmap = QPixmap('save.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        pixmap = QPixmap('exit.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        pixmap = QPixmap('save.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(500)
        pixmap = QPixmap('exit.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.cdLocButton.setEnabled(True)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```